# How to capitalize every other letter in a string/array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, for-loop

I am trying to capitalize every even numbered placeholder in a string in Swift. So the character in [0],[2],[4],[6] all get uppercased.

I have a declared variable:

```
var str = "This is a test"
```

I have an array that explodes the variable into an array:

```
let characters = Array(str) //Creates the array "["T", "h", "i", "s", " ", "i", "s", " ", "a", " ", "t", "e", "s", "t"]\n"
```

On top of that, I am creating an empty array to input the newly capitalized/lowercased letters

```
var newCharacters = Array<Character>()
```

And then declaring index at 0

```
var index = 0 //declaring the index at 0
```

I am trying to figure out how to create the for loop that will sniff out the even numbered array item and then capitalize the character found in it.

I have created a for loop that will manipulate the even numbered placeholders in the array, I just do not know the syntax to capitalize the string of every other one:

```
for letter in characters {

   if index % 2 == 0 {

     }

}
```

I am trying to figure out: what the syntax is to capitalize every other letter (even numbers in the array), put them in the new array, and then convert it back to a string.

The end result should be:

```
"ThIs iS TeSt"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine `enumerated`, `map`, and `joined` in sequence to create the result:

```
let str = "This is a test"

let result = str.enumerated()
                .map { $0.offset % 2 == 0 ? String($0.element).uppercased() : String($0.element) }
                .joined()

print(result)
```

> ```
> ThIs iS A TeSt
> ```

---

**Explanation:**

1. A `String` can be enumerated as if it were an array of `Character`.  Calling `.enumerated()` on a `String` causes it to produces a sequence of `(offset: Int, element: Character)` tuples.
2. `map` takes a sequence and creates an array.  The closure following `map` is called for each element of the sequence in turn and the value that the closure returns becomes the next element in the new array.
3. `$0` is the default name for the value passed to map.  In this case, we're passing the `(offset: Int, element: Character)` tuple.  `$0.offset` is the position of the character in the `String`, and `$0.element` is the character.
4. The ternary operator is used here to return the `uppercased()` `String` that is created from the `Character` if the offset is even or just the `String` if the offset is odd.
5. The result of the `map` is `[String]`, and `joined()` is then used to join the array of `String` back into a single `String`.

Comment: Wow this is it! Thank you so much. I am still learning the basics of Swift. So I have some follow-up questions.

- 1. Enumerated basically breaks the array into each placeholder? I.E. [0], [1], [2].. etc .etc?

- 2. I see that joined() is used, is this for putting the array back into its original joined entity?

- 3. I have to learn what .map is, but the logic in the brackets -- it seems that you are saying "For all array numbers that are divisible by 2, I want that string element to be capitalized" correct?

Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer with an explanation of how it works.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I think I am finally understanding. Just a few more clarifications:

1. Enumeration does not create the array but merely explodes the String into a sequence?

2. I now understand that .map does the actual creation of the array. Is it basically saying 'result' is now the new array?

3.$0.offset is essentially the [0],[1],[2] value whereas $0.element is the actual letter inside [0],[1],[2]? Your explanation makes perfect sense.
4. So "String($0.element).uppercased()" is basically you saying place the new element into the new array but uppercase?

Comment: 1. Correct. You can turn the sequence into an array with `Array()`.  `Array(str)` gives you an array of the characters in `str`, and `Array(str.enumerated())` gives you an array of the tuples. 2. `map` creates a new array, but we call `.joined()` on that array turning it into a string before it is assigned to `result`. 3. Correct 4. Correct

Comment: Very nice. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

One way is using `stride`:

```
var str = "This is a test" 
var chars = Array(str).map { String($0) }
for i in stride(from: 0, to: chars.count, by: 2) {
  chars[i] = chars[i].uppercased()
}
var hiphopcasedStr = chars.joined()
```

Note that while you're in Unicode land, some characters uppercase to multicharacter strings, so array of `Character` is not quite appropriate (thus the conversion to array of `String`).

Comment: *"some characters uppercase to multicharacter strings"* – an example is the german ["ß"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ß) which becomes "SS" in uppercase.

Comment: @MartinR It used to become "SS", but uppercase ß is (optional) part of official othography since 2017: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_ẞ

Comment: @ModusTollens Heh, look at that. Anyway, my Swift version 4.1.2 still hasn't gotten the memo. Need to update and see if it changes anything...

Comment: Even the latest Unicode standard defines in https://www.unicode.org/Public/12.0.0/ucd/CaseFolding-12.0.0d1.txt the uppercase version of "ß" (00DF) as "SS" (0073 0073).

Comment: @MartinR Yes, default casing is mapping ß to SS. ß to ẞ requires tailored casing. Still, the uppercase ẞ will probably become more common in the future. It is supposed to make identification more safe since uppercase is often used in official documents.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
var str = "This is a test"
var result = [String]()
for (index,element) in str.enumerated() {
    var val:String =  String(element).lowercased()
    if index % 2 == 0 {
        val = String(element).uppercased()
    }
    result.append(val)
}

print(result.joined())
```

result

> ThIs iS A TeSt